# Rotating captured frame from Samplebuffer in CGContext

Tags: ios, swift, camera, rotation, cgcontext

I'm working with front Camera, when I capture the frames, they are rotated 90 degrees CCW. I want to rotate captured image in CGContext (because I read Core Graphic is much faster than other frameworks).

Here is my code:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    let imageBuffer =  CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer!, 0)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer!, 0)

    let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer!, 0)

    let lumaBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer!, 0)

    let grayColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

    let context = CGContext(data: lumaBuffer,
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                            space: grayColorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue);

    let transform1 = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    context!.concatenate(transform1)

    //context!.rotate(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2)) // also not working!
    let dstImage = context!.makeImage()

    detect(image: dstImage!)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone searching how to actually physically rotate the buffer by any angle here's how you can do it. Add this to the top of your file:

```
static double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}

static double ScalingFactorForAngle(double angle, CGSize originalSize) {
    double oriWidth = originalSize.height;
    double oriHeight = originalSize.width;
    double horizontalSpace = fabs( oriWidth*cos(angle) ) + fabs( oriHeight*sin(angle) );
    double scalingFactor = oriWidth / horizontalSpace ;
    return scalingFactor;
}

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = NULL;
CIContext *context = nil;
CIImage *ci_originalImage = nil;
CIImage *ci_transformedImage = nil;

CIImage *ci_userTempImage = nil;


static inline void RotatePixelBufferToAngle(CVPixelBufferRef thePixelBuffer, double theAngle) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        if (context==nil) {
            rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: (__bridge id)rgbColorSpace,
                                                       kCIContextOutputColorSpace : (__bridge id)rgbColorSpace}];
        }

        long int w = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(thePixelBuffer);
        long int h = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(thePixelBuffer);

        ci_originalImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:thePixelBuffer];
        ci_userTempImage = [ci_originalImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6)];
        //        CGImageRef UICG_image = [context createCGImage:ci_userTempImage fromRect:[ci_userTempImage extent]];

        double angle = theAngle;
        angle = angle+M_PI;
        double scalingFact = ScalingFactorForAngle(angle, CGSizeMake(w, h));


        CGAffineTransform transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(w/2.0, h/2.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -w/2.0, -h/2.0);

        //rotate it by applying a transform
        ci_transformedImage = [ci_originalImage imageByApplyingTransform:transform];

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(thePixelBuffer, 0);

        CGRect extentR = [ci_transformedImage extent];
        CGPoint centerP = CGPointMake(extentR.size.width/2.0+extentR.origin.x,
                                      extentR.size.height/2.0+extentR.origin.y);
        CGSize scaledSize = CGSizeMake(w*scalingFact, h*scalingFact);
        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(centerP.x-scaledSize.width/2.0, centerP.y-scaledSize.height/2.0,
                                     scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height);


        CGImageRef cg_img = [context createCGImage:ci_transformedImage fromRect:cropRect];
        ci_transformedImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:cg_img];

        ci_transformedImage = [ci_transformedImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0/scalingFact, 1.0/scalingFact)];
        [context render:ci_transformedImage toCVPixelBuffer:thePixelBuffer bounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h) colorSpace:NULL];

        CGImageRelease(cg_img);
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(thePixelBuffer, 0);

    }
}
```

Go to the captureOutput:**captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection** and apply the function:

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixBuf = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
RotatePixelBufferToAngle(pixBuf, radians(45.0));
```

where **45.0 - is the desired angle**

Note that this is not only rotates but also scales the image so that it fills the video dimensions (kind of like Aspect Fill). You can turn the scaling off by modifying **scalingFact** variable.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching and reading articles, I found my solution inside AVCaptureConnection class!
I need only ask connection to rotate frame inside buffer with following sample code inside the capture function!!

```
if connection.isVideoOrientationSupported
{
     connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
}
     if connection.isVideoMirroringSupported
{
     connection.isVideoMirrored = true
}
```

that's all!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
```

You can change the orientation of the buffer to get the correct image, here you have an example as I made it:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation iOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

if(iOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    [connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];
}
else{
    [connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
}
```

Hope it helps.